# command line sftp: email address as username

Tags: shell, email, sftp

I need to connect to an sftp server from Mac OS X and the username given is an email address (someone@example.com)

So my connection string looks like:

```
sftp someone@example.com@ftp.example.com
```

The connection does not accept the password so I assume it is confused by the double "@".

I tried to escape the first "@" with "\@" But that crashed the sftp server and would only have an effect for the shell I'd think.

What is the proper way to escape this in order to get it to work.

Unfortunately the sftp command on Mac OS X does not allow me an option for interactive username prompt.

Comment: *Why would they DOOOO that?!*

Comment: As I'm told, some hosting panel that uses the e-mail as ssh login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an entry for the host in `~/.ssh/config` that has the desired name.

```
Host stupidadminhost
    HostName ssh.example.com
    User somewhere@outthere.com
```

Then just SFTP to `stupidadminhost` instead, with no given username.

Answer (score 2):

```
sftp -o User=someone@example.com ftp.example.com
```

Comment: Passing in the username like this works but still, The results is the same as if I had called sftp someone@example.com@ftp.example.com

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I use YummyFTP. It bypasses a lot of the complicated options and gives you a visual interface. It has been a time saver for me with lots of different sites to interact with.

Answer (score -3):

```
sftp "someone@example.com"@ftp.example.com
```

This does the trick too.

Comment: -1 The quotes will be gone by the time `sftp` sees the argument string.